# Cannot find Symbol and function cannot be applied : Java

Tags: java

```
class Demo2 
{
    int i=1,j=2;
    void fun1()
    {
        i=i+1;
        j=j+1;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Demo2 d1=new Demo2();
        d1.fun1();
        d1.fun1();
        d1.fun1();
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

symbol cannot find and func cant be applied errors are showing Please help me i am a basic learner....

Comment: Follow some basic java tutorials :)

Answer (score 3):

There are several errors in the code. I've commented and suggested some working code.

```
class Demo2 
{

    void fun1()
    {
        i=i+1; //i has not been initialized
        j=j+1; //j has not been initialized 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Demo2 d1=new Demo2();
        d1.fun1(1);//"fun1" does not accept a parameter.
        d1.fun1();
        d1.fun1();
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Here is a working Demo2 class that may help you along:

```
class Demo2
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    public void fun1(int param)
    {
        i=i+param;
        j=j+param;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Demo2 d = new Demo2();
        d.fun1(1);//adds 1 to both i and j
        d.fun1(2);//adds 2 to both i and j
        System.out.println("i is equal to " + i);
        System.out.println("j is equal to " + j);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code it helped me but now i have to understand the diff from previous program

Comment: The main problems were the following: 1) You must initialize variables before you call them. You can not do i=i+1 until you say "int i = (some number)". 2) If you want to call a method and pass something in such as  fun1(1); the method must accept that data type in its parameters. I.E. fun1(int param) since 1 is an integer.

Comment: I would suggest picking up a text book in java or looking up "basic java syntax". This will help you gain a rudimentary grasp of the programming language.

Answer (score 0):

You Does not declare `i` and `j` and doesnot defined a method `fun1` with one argument

Comment: class Demo2 
{
 int i=1,j=2;
 void fun1()
 {
  i=i+1;
     j=j+1;
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
   
  Demo2 d1=new Demo2();
  d1.fun1();
  d1.fun1();
  d1.fun1();
  System.out.println("Hello World!");
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

It's very important to understand why your code does not compile, or you will not be able to do anything else even if it gets fixed.

For starters, declare `i` and `j` by putting them right under your class declaration

```
class Demo2 {
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
```

Now look at where you defined `void fun1()`.  You don't allow it to accept any parameters.  So `d1.fun1();` is allowed but `d1.fun1(1);` is not.  You did not define a function named `fun1` that accepts an int as a parameter.  You would have to define it like so:

```
void fun1(int input) {
    // Whatever you wanted this function to do
}
```